# How to use window.ethereum to read from EVM storage slots since window.web3 got deprecated in latest metamask update?

Tags: web3js, metamask, storage, get-storage-at

I was playing [Capture the Ether](https://capturetheether.com/challenges/lotteries/guess-the-random-number/) challenge and in one of the challenge we had to read data from storage slot in the EVM.
I referred this medium article: https://medium.com/@saurfang/lets-play-capture-the-ether-lotteries-part-i-4e0b40687efd . The relevant part is shown below.

[image]

I opened the console in my browser and ran this code. **It gives the error:**

[image]

My question is how do i use window.ethereum for performing the same action.

Metamask breaking changes documentation(it shows how to use the window.ethereum but not my required function): https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#table-of-contents

Comment: You can import your own copy of web3.

Answer (score 0):

[Web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.1/getting-started.html) (e.g. Web3.js) is a wrapper around a “provider” or RPC.  That is what you see in the Medium article.  You should note that capitalized “Web3” is the type/class, and lowercase “web3” is the instantiated variable.  For example:

```
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
```

Also, if you have MetaMask installed, then the injected `window.ethereum` can be used without a wrapper.  You will use the [request( method )](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#methods) function and pass a command name such as `getStorageAt` as the `method` argument.  Other arguments will be passed in the `params` argument.